# Finding the source code in visual studio (C#)

Tags: c#

I had an application which has written by C# (Visual studio). Now when I try to see the source code `(form.cs)`, I can't find and open it But When I run the application, it runs correctly.
By the way, I did not change the name of `form`.

What has happened?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you loose the source of the app and now need it back and all you have is an *.exe file ?

Comment: yeap, exactly and my datasets are in .exe path. @Aviatrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have lost your form.cs file and you have just the `.exe` you can use a [decompiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)
it will spit your code back, but it won't be as pretty as before but you will have and be able to edit it and compile it again.